# Changing background colour of listview item on click - and remembering it

Tags: android, listview

I am populating a listview with strings from an ArrayList.
When a listview item is clicked i would like to change the background colour to green. <- **Issue number one** because I cannot change the item which is clicked.

After an item is clicked, I am adding its index to the list of items the user has selected, when the listview is first loaded I need it to set the background colour of all the listview items which have been selected to green too. <- **Issue number 2** - I have been trying to do this with a for loop but do not know how to refer to a specific item in the listview to set the background colour!

Essentially, i think if someone can help me in how to change the colour of a selected listview item, i should be able to do the same thing but in a loop for all the userFoodPref which are saved?

```
    animalsNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    userFoodPref = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    getUserSelection();
    getAnimalNames();
    // Create The Adapter with passing ArrayList as 3rd parameter
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, animalsNameList);
    // Set The Adapter
    animalList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);




    // register onClickListener to handle click events on each item
    animalList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        // argument position gives the index of item which is clicked
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if(userFoodPref.contains(i)
            ){
                userFoodPref.remove(i);}
                else {
                userFoodPref.add(i);
                View item = animalList.getSelectedView();
                item.setBackgroundColor(0x0000FF00);
            }

            String selectedAnimal=animalsNameList.get(i);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Animal Selected : "+selectedAnimal,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So, did it work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, the problem is that when you set the backround of the item and then by example scroll the list and comeback to the previous position, it doens't remember that the backround is green for this specifix item.

I have faced this problem and to solve it easily :

Create a list a string for your name and a boolean (true = green, false = not green) and create an adapter for it and simply add
 if (list.get(position).getBoolean) {
Currentitem.setBackgroundColor(0x0000FF00)}

And when you click on a item simply set the boolean of the item position to true and call notifydatasetchanged()